# What this exception means? C# winforms

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display images from a database table to my dataGridView control.

Other cells display image. But some doesn't and throws this exception:

[image]

What does this exception means? What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, it means that your image data is invalid. Try extracting the image data by another means, like a simple console app, and pass that to `Image.FromStream`. Or serialize it out and try to open it in an external image editor. You might get a more informative error message that way.

Comment: @yonan: Just prepare a simple application, or even a function of your existing application, that instead of passing the image data to the DataGridView, just writes it out to a file. `System.IO.WriteAllBytes(imageData);`, or similar. Then open that from Microsoft Paint, or PhotoShop (or my favorite, [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/)).

Comment: i just did this  byte[] data = (byte[]) dt.Rows[0]["IMAGE"];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: @yonan: Ok - what happened when you opened those images from an external editor, like I described?

Comment: Sorry sir but I don't know how to extract the picture from database.

Comment: @yonan: Did what I describe not work (though the signature was a little off)? `System.IO.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\image.jpg", data);` Change the file extension, of course, to whatever file format you're storing. You already have the byte array, as you showed above.

Comment: I got this error: The type or namespace name 'WriteAllBytes' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: My mistake: it's `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes`. But yonan, honestly, you should be more familiar with the Framework than that... Simply plugging "WriteAllBytes" into MSDN would give you a wealth of information.

Comment: yes sir I admit. I have no formal education in programming. I rely on books and online forums. I self study on programming.

Comment: By the way, do the other images in your database display properly? Is that the only image that's giving you problems? If you haven't tested your other images, you should do that.

Comment: If I were you, I'd step back and walk through some tutorials before jumping straight into web and database development. You're going to get yourself hopelessly confused. You might start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436.aspx

Comment: yes sir, the other images display properly. but there are couple of images that are not showing also. I already extracted some of the images but the other won't open in an image editor.

Comment: ...and acquaint yourself with the MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) library documentation. It really will save you all the time, and make you appear smarter than other programmers.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361664.aspx

Comment: Is it possible that these images are just plain corrupted? What type of image are they (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc.), and does DataGridView support that type?

Comment: Here's the list of supported types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at62haz6.aspx

Comment: I tried displaying a certain image with a particular id in a Picture Box. Maybe those images that don't show are corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6.aspx) your call will result in this exception if the Stream has an invalid format
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If some invalid in bytes entered then it wont display properly.

If you tried with a `Insert query` , then this problem may come. Try to insert image from code only.Hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to indicate that there was an error creating the image from a `Stream` (probably handled within ADO.NET rather than in your code).  If it's working for some images and not others then start by double-checking the data in the database, and look for differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

There might be the error from database.Please once check your Code again

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, the images display in some rows but not others it's the data, not your code - The images have been captured incorrectly.